# how to build a android system

Tags: android, build, makefile

I have the android resource.

1. . build/envsetup.sh
2. make

above two steps I have finish the source build, and the out directory has some useful file.
but I can't understand how to make a zip file like update.zip.
I want to flash my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Have you been following [this](http://source.android.com/source/building-dream.html) step-by-step instruction list? You only have to take care not to build for the specific device described there if you don't build for the ADP.